# Can I customize the League of Legends UI?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is there anyway to customise the UI in LoL to make it easier for you, like where your target's name plate is, where the kill feeds appear, or where your abilities bar is? Or is it possible to have add-ons, like World of Warcraft, to make it easier when playing?

Comment: clunky and horrible? why?

Comment: The layout is horrible the bars at the bottom and the way the inventory is laid out would like it to only take one row and to make it all bit more transparent and the kill feed in center of screen in a team fight gets in way alot

Comment: You can drag/drop windows that pop up, like the surrender dialogue.

Comment: @Toast, those surrender dialogues are REALLY messy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[You can customize](http://blog.fileplanet.com/2011/06/23/customize-your-league-of-legends/) the UI and use addons. One place you can look for addons is [here](http://leaguecraft.com/uimods), and [this blog](http://blog.fileplanet.com/2011/06/23/customize-your-league-of-legends/) talks about an officially supported mod that allows you to change your UI, among other things.

Comment: Didn't even knew it existed, thanks!